# sqlite3 nodejs module, How do we wait for db#serialize to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

How do we make sure that db#serialize is completed before executing the start timer code again?. I see await/async with a promise to be the only option to fix this.  Is there any better way to solve this ?. db#serialize should have provided a completed call back.

db#each has a completed call back, but other db# functions don't provide that option. In general d#serialize should have provided this option

```
function checkLoop()
{
  //console.log("Checking for any request to process")
  db.serialize(function(){
    db.each('select * from prepare_updates where finished_at IS NULL',
              function(err, row){
                if(err === null )
                {
                  console.log("preparing updates for " + row.id)
                  // Some processing
                }
      })
  })
  console.log("Starting timer again ")
  if(!stop)
  {
    setTimeout(function(){checkLoop()},2000);  
  }
}
```

Comment: 3 years, and no answer.